# Add CONCAT Increment to varchar(128)

Tags: mysql

Hello I'm trying to update a table to convert my product text references to a masked number.

I have:
Product a, product b, product c.... upto 1500 products right now
I need to change to:
PP1001, PP1002, PP1003 for all of them.... it should be always PPXXXX - where XXX is the incrementing number.

So far I have tried the below statement:

```
UPDATE `cl13-workflow`.`llx_product`
SET `ref`= concat('PP','1000'+1) WHERE `rowid` ='10';
```

Can anyone help where I have gone wrong?  I need to apply it to the whole product table.  I'm presuming if I remove the WHERE it would work but it won't increment the number digits.

[MySQL Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b8MVj.png)

[MySQL Products Table Rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mrk9J.png)

```
Table: llx_product
Columns:
rowid int(11) AI PK 
ref varchar(128) 
entity int(11) 
ref_ext varchar(128) 
datec datetime 
tms timestamp 
virtual tinyint(4) 
fk_parent int(11) 
label varchar(255) 
description text 
note text 
customcode varchar(32) 
fk_country int(11) 
price double(24,8) 
price_ttc double(24,8) 
price_min double(24,8)
```

.... there is more columns

Comment: Can you show a snapshot of the current `llx_product` table?  Do you really have a `rowid` column?

Comment: addition with string will be string concatanation and not arithmetic operation

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen added pictures

Comment: no, don't add pictures rather post it as text

Comment: @Rahul added table as text

Answer (score 0):

Create a AUTO_INCREMENT field in your table then you can do it like this.

**sample**

```
UPDATE `cl13-workflow`.`llx_product` SET `ref`= concat('PP',LPAD(id, 4, '0')) WHERE `rowid` ='10';
```

Comment: If I apply that to the whole table, will the numbers start from PP1xxx so if I now have 1500 products, the last product would be PP2500?

Comment: Could you please clarify whether your statement can be applied to the whole table?